# Visual studio (C#) 'Hot code replace'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've previously developed in Java use Eclipse IDE and was used to a feature call `HCR`. This features is, as far as I know, only available in Eclipse. It allows you to replace code while the application is being debugged. No need to pause or stop the debugging session, just modify the file and, on save, replace the code in the JVM. There's [a bit more details here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F) is I'm not too clear.

Now, I'm curious to know if there's a similar feature in Visual Studio (either a feature or an extension). I know about `Edit and Continue`, but this requires pausing the application execution and it doesn't allow to edit the file while the code is running.

Comment: Yes, VS supports that. But you must first be debugging the edited code (by a breakpoint hit)

Comment: Edit and Continue is all you have.

Comment: Does it really make a difference to how you "hot replace" code? The idea behind Edit and Continue is to make it as safe as possible to do such "hot patches" - allowing you to change code while your application is doing who knows what sounds like a great way to randomly crash your application :)

Comment: @Luaan Really? At least in VS2010 I´m stuck with this annyoing behaviour.

Comment: @Luaan perhaps you don't need this feature, but it's a great time saver for a game developer when it comes to debugging rendering in OpenGL or DirectX. Edit and Continue is useful, but having to pause the execution also breaks the delta time in the game. It's a lot more efficient to just have the source file beside the application and being able to see the changes apply instantly. I understand it's "possible" in VS, but it's not as powerful as Eclipse.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, I just checked it in VS2015 to make sure, and it indeed works :) There's probably still a lot of cases where it's not going to work, but it's getting better with each new version of VS :)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I've never really had any issues with that, but I guess it's one of the features you don't really care about until you have them and lose them :D If you're really serious, you could just make your own hot-patching that allows you to do whatever you need by recompiling the whole project, but that's probably a bit of an overkill. Or just trim your delta time in debug mode, on the assumption that very long delta times are probably the result of debugging and not long frames :D

Comment: @Luaan I might just end up doing some runtime compilation with a reference to the debugger class that I can swap with the new compiled code. I guess this is as close as I'm going to get I believe!

Comment: It depends on how much work you're willing to put into this. It's quite possible to replace an assembly as a whole as long as you keep things safe and do the replacement at a safe point (e.g. the start of a frame update), especially if you make sure data structures don't change (can Eclipse handle that?). It's just that there's probably a compromise that will work well enough for you without requiring tons of contracts and R&D :D

Comment: Yeah well, Eclipse doesn't handle structural changes, and AFAIK Edit-and-Continue doesn't either. That's not a huge deal, I understand why it would be super hard to handle. But changing a method structure, VS already handles this. It would just be nice to have a faster way to do it. I can change this method about 10-20 times before I get the expected result. Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll implement my own messaging system for debugging and compiling at runtime. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit while debugging when you broke into your code (e.g. by a breakpoint or an exception). However there are some limitations on what you can edit while in a debugging-session.

Basically you can only change the internal but not the external behaviour of any member within your class. Having said this you cannot change the parameter-list or the return-value of your members or even their name. Furthermore there are some annyoing ones like lambdas, delegates and some conde-contracts that break the debgugger from continuing its work.

There might be reasons you wish to change some of these features while debugging, but the VS-designers chosed a highly save appraoch that your changes will not make your application crash while debugging.